# Historic Option chain for NSE stock not showing full data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the historic stock options data of a week from NSE website. I am able to get only around 50 records or so which are shown in UI.
If I download the data using the "Download (.csv)" button available, it shows the full week's worth of option data.

Why is this and how can I get the full data for the week?
[image]

Comment: is your question related to python? what code are you trying? [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

> Why

Likely because it would be slow for the website to display a full week's worth of data.

> How can I get the full data?

You can get the full data by downloading the .CSV file that it offers you.
Please show what code you have used so far or what you have attempted.

If you want to use Python to read this data, try using Pandas, not webscraping. Webscraping is likely going to be slower, and as you mentioned, limited to just the displayed data. Here's an example, where the .CSV file is called "options.csv"

```
import pandas as pd
my_data = pd.read_csv("options.csv")
# The options data is now stored in a Dataframe.
```